# zendesk - enduser login with username and password

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

We are developing a mobile app.

In this app we want our END USER to able to login with there email id + the password they have from our zendesk.

I can not find any way to let a END USER login with email + password. And after that, make tickets and see his open tickets.

We are using the CORE API at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the docs for the [iOS](https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios/set_an_identity) and [Android](https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android/set_an_identity) SDKs?

You can set up an `AnonymousIdentity` with email and name after your users auth into your app. This will give you an identity which can be used to create tickets.

There are limitations with `AnonymousIdentity`, described in the docs. The other option is `JwtIdentity`, this requires a bit of backend development to get up and running.